# Assign a reportDocument object to a ReportViewer on run time and show it (ASPX,Crystal): update: visibility:hidden

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, crystal-reports-2008, reportdocument

First at all, thanks in advance.

Well, I would like to show a report in the reportViewer Control from crystalReports.

I load manually the report (from an rpt file), it's in a ReportDocument object, I know is loaded without problems, because I can export to PDF/XLS and it works perfectly, but is not show it when I assign the report object as ReportSource of my ReportViewer control.

After load the report (at Init_Complete event) I'm doing this:

```
    crViewer.ReportSource = reportObject
```

But the web page doesn't show the report. Any idea ?

Thanks.

**Update:** for some reason the DIV for the reportViewer has this style:

```
visibility:hidden
```

I just need to know how to remove it or avoid it. (and of course I would like to know why that style is added).

**Update 2:** Besides the "visibility:hidden" the Crystal Image Handler isn't working, and all the report is in "html", I'm trying to use the report viewer control, to have a similar behavior to the reportViewer on WinForms, I'm trying to add the handler to the WebConfig but the tag  isn't recognized.

**Update 3:** :( I couldn't add the handler anyone have a clue ?

Comment: I guess, finally find my problem, the div generated by the reportViewerControl has this style: "visibility:hidden"